# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Non-negative number required. Parameter name: newSize' (RFID, HIDLibrary)

Tags: c#, barcode, rfid

I am trying to continuously read input from a rfid USB reader using HIDLibrary.

```
_device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (_device != null)
        {
            _device.OpenDevice();

            _device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler;
            _device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;

            _device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;

            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);

            Console.WriteLine("Reader found, press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            _device.CloseDevice();
        }
```

private static void OnReport(HidReport report)
{
if (!_device.IsConnected) { return; }

```
        var cardData = new Data(report.Data);

        Console.WriteLine(!cardData.Error ? Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cardData.CardData) : cardData.ErrorMessage);

        _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
    }

    private static void DeviceAttachedHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device attached.");
        _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
    }

    private static void DeviceRemovedHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device removed.");
    }
```

I am getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: newSize'.

cant find from where this is happening. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _device.ReadReport(OnReport); This is causing the error.